# Python string have not control characters

Tags: python, string, control-characters

i have proxy string:

```
proxy = '127.0.0.1:8080'
```

i need check is it real string:

```
def is_proxy(proxy):
    return not any(c.isalpha() for c in proxy)
```

to skip string like:

```
fail_proxy = 'This is proxy: 127.0.0.1:8080'
```

but some time i have like:

```
fail_proxy2 = '127.0.0.1:8080\r'
is_proxy(fail_proxy2) is True
True
```

need False

Comment: Character type blacklisting is the wrong way to go about this. You'll just fail on inputs like `1.1.1` or `::::`.

Comment: no it works
'.'.isalpha() == False

Comment: Fix whatever is leaving carriage returns in your data in the first place. Most likely, you are reading from a file without proper end-of-line handling.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following specific approach using `re` module(regexp):

```
import re

def is_proxy(proxy):
    return re.fullmatch('^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5}$', proxy) is not None

proxy1 = '127.0.0.1:8080'
proxy2 = '127.0.0.1:8080\r'

print(is_proxy(proxy1))   # True
print(is_proxy(proxy2))   # False
```

As for port number (`\d{1,5}`): range **1-65535** are available for port numbers